# Possible to Set a Frozen Row in Org-Mode Table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I use a standard org-mode table to store a lot of my own personal data. However, the tables have gotten quite large.

I need a way to have the top row stay visible.

Can I set this with `header-line-format` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069713/freeze-table-rows-in-emacs-org-mode) question on stackoverflow has two suggestions, including using elisp to set the header-line-format to the first line of the table.

It also suggests splitting the window horizontally and keeping the header in the upper window as a hackish workaround.

To use the code, add it to org-mode-hook as follows

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda()
  (setq-local header-line-format
    (list '(:eval
        (save-excursion
          (org-table-goto-line 1)
          (substring (thing-at-point 'line t) 0 -1)))))))
```

Comment: I read that question, but how do I set it for each different document? Each header will be at a different line for each document with a table.

Comment: @Adam Which method are you using?  The code should recognize which table you're in and do the right thing.

Comment: @usere2699 I tried to paste the code from the post you linked into my .init.el but nothing is different when I go into a file with an org-table and scroll past the header. I'm running emacs from the OS X terminal if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Adam, copying it into your init file won't do much (as you found), it has to be called when org-mode is started.  I've added an example.

Comment: ah! Thank you! I see the header-line now but when I scroll down past the header of my table nothing appears in the header-line.

Comment: Ah, it works! I needed to press Tab. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a package on Melpa that may be useful:
`orgtbl-show-header`

Comment: Please provide a little more information on the package and a link.